# Parse XML using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm using MS SQL2016 and I have an XML file that I need to parse to put various data elements into the separate fields.  For the most part everything works find except I need a little help to identify a particular node value. If I have (I put only a snippet of the xml here but it does show the problem)

```
             DECLARE @xmlString xml
             SET @xmlString ='<PubmedArticle>
               <MedlineCitation Status="PubMed-not-MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
              <PMID Version="1">25685064</PMID>
              <Article PubModel="Electronic-eCollection">
              <Journal>                
             <ISSN IssnType="Electronic">1234-5678</ISSN>
             <ISSN IssnType="Print">1475-2867</ISSN>
            <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
                <Volume>15</Volume>
                <Issue>1</Issue>
                <PubDate>
                    <Year>2015</Year>
                </PubDate>
            </JournalIssue>
           </Journal>
            </Article>
          </MedlineCitation>
         </PubmedArticle>'

select      
    nref.value('Article[1]/Journal[1]/ISSN[1]','varchar(max)') ISSN                 
    from @xmlString.nodes ('//MedlineCitation[1]') as R(nref)
```

I bypass the second ISSNType and read the first value available.  I need to pull both values.  What do I need to change?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read as second column:

```
SELECT      
    nref.value('Article[1]/Journal[1]/ISSN[1]','varchar(max)') ISSN,
    nref.value('Article[1]/Journal[1]/ISSN[2]','varchar(max)') ISSN2                 
FROM @xmlString.nodes('//MedlineCitation[1]') as R(nref)
```

Or

```
SELECT
    nref.value('ISSN[1]','varchar(max)') ISSN,
    nref.value('ISSN[2]','varchar(max)') ISSN2
FROM @xmlString.nodes('//MedlineCitation[1]/Article[1]/Journal[1]') as R(nref)
```

Or as a separate row:

```
SELECT nref.value('.','varchar(MAX)') ISSN
from @xmlString.nodes('//MedlineCitation[1]/Article[1]/Journal[1]/ISSN') as R(nref)
```

---

Update

If number of ISSNs may vary, I recommend normalize your resultset:

```
SELECT
    nref.value('.','varchar(MAX)') Issn,
    nref.value('@IssnType','varchar(MAX)') IssnType
FROM @xmlString.nodes('//MedlineCitation[1]/Article[1]/Journal[1]/ISSN') as R(nref)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input- Is there a way to identify the IssnType of that element?  Is it possible to add  the Print or Electronic to the nref.value string?  I can't guarantee that both values will be available and many times only one.

Comment: Updated my answer.